# Hiding input type by click event Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to hide the submit button but it didn't work. I wrote several alerts to test and it turned out that it never got into the click event. Can someone tell me where were my mistakes? Thanks a lot!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Dindin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="play">

    <p>What's your name?</p>
    <br><input type="text" name="name">
    <p>What time are you going to dinner?</p>
    <br><input type="time" name="time">
    <br><input type='submit' value='Submit'>

  </div>

  <script>
  alert("Hello");
    $('input:submit').click(function() {
        alert("Into click");
        storeInfo();
        showResult();
        $('.play').html("<input type='submit'value='Booked!'");
    }
    var answers= [];
    var storeInfo = function() {
        alert("Into storeInfo");
        $('input:submit').hide();
        answers.push([$('input:text').val(), $('input:time').val()]);
        var time = $('#time');
    }
    var showResult = function() {
        alert("Into showResult");
        $('.play').html('These are the people going to dinner near your time:');
        for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(answers[i][1] - time)/1000 =< 10000) {
                $('.play').html('<br>'+answers[i][0]+' '+answers[i][1]);
            }
        }
    }


  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You have errors in your JS, which is causing the JS not to run.  Look at your browser's console log (F12) and fix the errors.  For example, the line before `var answers = [];` should be `});` and not just `}`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing parenthesis and semicolon, which is causing an error in your JS.

[image: console]

```
$('input:submit').click(function() {
        alert("Into click");
        storeInfo();
        showResult();
        $('.play').html("<input type='submit'value='Booked!'");
    }); // <<<< here
```

You have other errors in your code that you also need to fix.  Look at F12 console log.  For example, this is incorrect:

```
 if (Math.abs(answers[i][1] - time)/1000 =< 10000) {
```

`=<` should be `<=`.

Also, you should be using [$(document).ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) in order to make sure your events are bound after the DOM has loaded.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into it! It works now.

Comment: @LanNgo - if this solution worked for you, you can mark it as the answer by selecting the checkmark near the top of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should place your jQuery code inside a

```
$(function() {
    // place your code here
});
```

Otherwise it might not work because jQuery is not "ready".

Answer (score -1):

You forgot all your closing parentheses for the functions, and also [the document ready event](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp)